# Запрос на удаление строки, в условии используется процент (%). MS Access

Tags: sql, access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо создать запрос на удаление записей, в которых *цена товара > 100* и *скидка на этот товар < 5*.

Написала запрос, он удаляет все записи, в которых цена больше 100, но при этом условие со скидкой не учитывается.

Как это можно исправить?

Сам запрос:

```
DELETE Заказано.Цена, Заказано.Скидка
  FROM Заказано
WHERE (((Заказано.Цена)>100) 
  AND ((Заказано.Скидка)<5));
```

Comment: А если вместо первой строки написать так `DELETE Заказано.*`?

Comment: Такой же результат

Comment: Тогда покажите структуру таблицы

Comment: Что именно вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Колонки таблицы с типами данных.

Comment: Добавила в описание

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас всё отлично. Не могли бы вы привести ещё пример данных, которые у вас в таблице хранятся? Пару строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю Скидка это в Процентах. Вам нужно использовать числовое значения процента

```
DELETE Заказано.Цена, Заказано.Скидка
  FROM Заказано
WHERE (((Заказано.Цена)>100) 
  AND ((Заказано.Скидка)<0.05));
```

так как 1 это 100%. Если вам нужно 5% тогда это будет 0,05 в числах

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо Вам большое :)